# Device specific error - s3dReadConfigFile "Can't open file for reading."

Tags: android, galaxy

I'm developing an application that communicates over the local network, and am trying to test on multiple devices. I have a Droid Incredible and a Samsung Galaxy S3 for testing right now. When I run the application on the Incredible, all works as intended. However, when I run the app on the GS3, I get the following error in LogCat:

> < s3dReadConfigFile:75 >: Can't open file for reading

A team mate with another GS3 <strike>does not get this error when he runs the application on that device</strike> also gets this error, but it took him a while to find it because of the volume of log output. What is the possible cause? Is this a configuration issue, a hardware issue, or something in my code?

Comment: FWIW, I get the same exact error (twice in a row) running a fresh ADT application on my S3.

Comment: Any context on what kind of code you are running? How to replicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several months of developing and continuing to receive this error on multiple devices running multiple apps, it seems at least to be a system issue. It does not result in any issues running apps on GS3s versus other devices, and it's also likely not anything to do with my code.

I have no idea what it means or how to mitigate it, but if you're receiving the error, you can probably just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your mates Galaxy S3 rooted...it may require root privilege to read s3dReadConfigFile config file...just a guess

Answer (score 0):

i have it too,
just unlock your phone, and make it ready to use.
than run your app from software (Eclipse - in my case)

Answer (score 0):

i have it too, 
just unlock your phone, and make it ready to use.
than run your app from software (Eclipse - in my case).