# Adreno200-EGLSUB: <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888 issue with Motorola Defy device

Tags: android, motorola

I have been facing strange issue in my one of Android application with Motorola Defy device. I have been testing the same application on HTC and Samsung devices and it is running perfectly without any issue, however when I test it with Motorola device, it starts getting crashes.

All log files shows Adreno200-EGLSUB: : Format RGBA_8888 error. Let me add one more thing that I am using SurfaceView and surfaceHolder class.

Could anyone know what possible reasons might be and it can be sorted out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, I tried to set

```
 getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

But still returned the same problem. I run on several thousands times, no further error was shown related to this one.
According to answers [Device specific error - s3dReadConfigFile "Can't open file for reading."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280681/device-specific-error-s3dreadconfigfile-cant-open-file-for-reading)

It will not affect the use of your application

Answer (score 0):

i have it too, 
just unlock your phone, and make it ready to use.
than run your app from software (Eclipse - in my case).