# Android application crashing on Motorola defy reason <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading

Tags: android, motorola

I have been working on an Android application for last couple of weeks. I have been testing it on Samsung s3 and HTC one without any issue.

However I brought Motorola defy and while started testing on it, application starts crashing. After looking into logcat I found following issue that might cause crash i.e.

```
<s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
```

Could any help me to fix this issue? Why is it crashing on Motorola not on any other Android devices?

Thanks in advance.

Here is full logcat

```
E 7183/Trace: error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
D 7183/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
D 7183/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
D 7183/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
D 7183/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
D 7183/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
D 7183/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I 7183/Adreno200-EGLSUB: <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
E 7183/: <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
E 7183/: <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
D 7183/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
I 7183/Adreno200-EGLSUB: <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
```

After that there is nothing happens and app crashes.

Comment: Please, post the full logcat with crash.

Comment: Thanks Nickolai for reply. I added logcat for more information.

Comment: There's a permission denied error. Are you trying to write on the phone itself, or on the SDCard?

Comment: It's better to post log with exception. it will look like "FATAL EXCEPTION"

Comment: sorry for late response. However I did not get any exception or any other error. I posted complete logcat.

Comment: I have the same problem on Galaxy S3, the code runs fine on Galaxy Nexus. Anyone care to check this one?

Comment: Several Galaxy Note 1 got this problem.

Comment: There is another post here, same issue, no solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15280681/969325

Comment: I just realized your username...

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this is worth the bounty, but this question has been asked and answered on SO before:
[Device specific error - s3dReadConfigFile "Can't open file for reading."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280681/device-specific-error-s3dreadconfigfile-cant-open-file-for-reading)

It appears to be an error caused by the Adreno GPU in the device. 
https://developer.qualcomm.com/discover/chipsets-and-modems/adreno-gpu

The GPU causes this error any time you create a GL Surface. The error seems to log but get handled by whatever drivers Quaalcom provides it is very common on Galaxy S3, but does not cause a crash on that device.

Perhaps someone at Quaalcom knows why the error crashes on Moto, but not Samsung.
https://developer.qualcomm.com/contact

I hope this helps you along a bit. My gut tells me this is a red herring: Its not what is causing your crash. But it is pretty hard to ignore an error message in a crashing app. Still, I would suggest looking for other possible culprits before spending too much time chasing down this error. On my devices, that error is shown on any open GL game I make, but never causes a crash or any other disruption. It only even causes the error on the Samsun G3 I have, not on my other (HTC) test devices.

Comment: thanks. Trying to give you the bounty points... it says I can in 23 hours

Comment: Thanks! has it been 24 hours yet?

Comment: I apology for being late (almost 2 months) at responding. I still could not find solution for this specific issue, however I changed the logic and not using open GL anymore. But I am still curious about the reason.

Comment: When you removed the OpenGL did the error go away? I assume yes. And as stated above, the error us called by the Quaalcom drivers. The driver throws and handles the error, using the android Log.e() to report the error. That's why it looks red, because they chose Log.e(). It seems it should probably be a Log.w() message since it doesn't seem to cause a problem outside of the driver but since I can't see the driver code, I can't say for sure.