# <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading error

Tags: java, android

I'm recieving an error when running on my galaxy s3 called ": Can't open file for reading" twice in my LogCat.

Here is my code:
 package com.example.speechrecognizertest;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

public static final String TAG = null;
private ListView wordList;
private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
private Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent; 
private boolean mIslistening; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button speechBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speech_btn);
wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.word_list);
PackageManager packManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> intActivities = packManager.queryIntentActivities(
        new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                                 RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                                 this.getPackageName());
if (!mIslistening)
{
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
} else {
    speechBtn.setEnabled(false);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Oops - Speech Recognition Not Supported!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
if (mSpeechRecognizer != null)
{
        mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
}
super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}



protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener
{

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
{               
    Log.d(TAG, "onBeginingOfSpeech"); 
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
{

}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
 }

@Override
public void onError(int error)
{
     mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

    Log.d(TAG, "error = " + error);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
{

}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
{

}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "OnReadyForSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results)
{
    //Log.d(TAG, "onResults"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    ArrayList<String> suggestedWords =   results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    // matches are the return values of speech recognition engine
    // Use these values for whatever you wish to do

    wordList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.word, suggestedWords));



}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB){}}


}
```

My LogCat is displaying idsactly what I described. Would really appreciate a fix guys!

Comment: May be a duplicate: check the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280681/device-specific-error-s3dreadconfigfile-cant-open-file-for-reading

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this for a number of months on my S3 and it's never appeared to cause any problems. [The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280681/device-specific-error-s3dreadconfigfile-cant-open-file-for-reading) sounds probable to me.