# Samsung GS3 Specific Error s3dReadConfigFile. Works on any other Android device.

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile

So I have a MainActivity that goes like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_p); 
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            jump();
        }

    }, 3000);
}
```

With a Layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingTop="5sp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
     />
```

When I debug it on a Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 4.0.3), the image appears and the jump function is successfully called. When I debug it on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1.2), LogCat throws this error.

```
05-18 19:51:05.832: E/(20438): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
```

The jump function is never called and the app crashes completely. I do not have any idea what this error is and how to fix it. This question has also been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280681/device-specific-error-s3dreadconfigfile-cant-open-file-for-reading) but has no answers as of this writing.

The application works as long as the imageview is not set a source. If I comment out this line I still get the error but the jump function is called. If I don't call setContentView() at all, the error never appears.